# "Logical file 'Movies' is not part of database"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-restore

Usually when I need to make a manual change I just back up my SQL Server Management Studio 2012 database called **Movies**, then upload it to my host, then use their restore feature to implement it.

I am still in a testing phase so data does not need to be kept that is acquired online, however I wanted to try keeping the data today so I used the host's backup option which created a **DB_76779_test_backup.bak** file for me.

I then download this and "attempted" to updated it's information into the SQL database on my machine (**Movie**) which I believe is where I messed everything up.

From what I remember I right-clicked my database "Movies" and selected "Tasks -> Restore -> Database", I kept everything as is, but for `Source` I selected **Device** then chose the `DB_76779_test_backup.bak` file and and below that selected "Movies" as the Database and hit OK.

[image]

This seemed to work fine, so I opened and edited the tables values that needed to be changed. Then as usual, I just backed it up, FTPed it to the host, and restored my database.

I got an error however when trying to restore and my support told me the following.

> "Logical file 'Movies' is not part of database 'DB_76779_test'. Use
> RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names."
>
> I'm afraid we only support restores of databases that contain only 1
> .mdf file and 1 .ldf file with no extra partitions.

I am assuming that since the only different thing I did this time was restore my database on my computer is that somehow I broke it, or created more than 1 mdf and ldf file (no clue what those even are). All I was trying to do was keep the actual data from online, so I am not even sure if that was correct way to go about this, but regardless I am unable to restore the database on my host now..

What mistake have I made? I only know a basic level of databasing and not much of the "under the hood" mechanics.

Comment: There is `DB_76779_test_data` and `DB_76779_test_log`

Comment: When I restore I go to a CPanel, and I click an Icon labeled **MS SQL Manager**, I then click Restore, and select my Movies.bak. Here is the error image if that helps at all. **[IMGUR ERROR](http://imgur.com/b4R5Bjz)**. The host is Winhost, if that helps too.

Comment: So, as mentioned in the thread I have always backed up my local DB then uploaded it, that was always the DB Movies with the file movies.bak. This other DB_76779_test file was from the host's backup, and the file that I attempted to restore my Movies DB with.That make sense?

Comment: I've cleaned up my comments to help keep it short. What it comes down to is that the there is a mdf and ldf file for your database. The mdf is the main file and the ldf is the transaction log file. The error is telling you that the bak doesn't contain logical file `Movies`. You can verify this by running the following `restore filelistonly
from disk = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\test2.bak'`. Make sure you edit it to point to your BAK file. The error message states that they only support 1 mdf file and 1 ldf file and your BAK could have say 2 ldfs.

Comment: Okay, so I am just copy/pasting this `restore filelistonly from disk = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\test2.bak'` into a `New Query`? (modifying the directory path that is)

Comment: I think it is working now. This is what I did, it was just a guess. I asked for another backup from the server (since I knew that was fine because I couldn't restore anything to it), I then did a Restore on Movie from that backup, but this time I changed the file name so that they ended in \Movies.mdf and .ldf, and then I also checked a box called overwrite existing backup sets. (it just sounded like a good thing to check). Anyways, the restore worked with that.. any idea why that worked?

Comment: oh to clarify, I changed the names during the restore along with overwrite all file. Then checked the overwrite existing backup sets during the backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That SSMS dialog is a little difficult to work with some times.  It looks like you want to rename your database to Movies.  The problem is when you change the name field it does not update the logical names it is using for the files.  IIRC simply switching to the Files "tab" on the left will update it and then you can restore fine.  That or do your restore with the "old" name and then name the database after restore.

Comment: Okay so I just need to re-restore my Movies DB from the host's .bak, but during that process I just need to click on the File menu to the left? I feel like I went there before but it did not update to Movies, it remained the DB_76779_ files.

Comment: Missed the SSMS 2012 part.  This was a solution to a similar issue on a previous version of SQL.  Tried doing a basic rename during restore on 2012 and it did not have an issue.  Sorry.

Comment: I think it is working now. This is what I did, it was just a guess. I asked for another backup from the server (since I knew that was fine because I couldn't restore anything to it), I then did a Restore on Movie from that backup, but this time I changed the file name so that they ended in \Movies.mdf and .ldf, and then I also checked a box called overwrite existing backup sets. (it just sounded like a good thing to check). Anyways, the restore worked with that.. any idea why that worked?

Comment: oh to clarify, I changed the names during the restore along with overwrite all file. Then checked the overwrite existing backup sets during the backup

Comment: That's strange.  I would not have expected that solution to fix that error message.  It is possible there is some issue where it gives you the wrong error message for "cannot overwrite existing database".  It seems more like something is different between the first and second backups.  Maybe the first one got corrupted during download.  Can you try the same thing on the "original" database?

Comment: I have no idea what caused it. But editing the files "may" have helped in the end so I shall award you the answer haha. Thanks for the help! :)